Angular notify parent of child input changes
I have a parent component with a data object, which I pass the same object into two child components (all components are onpush strategy). Each of these child components have a form that update the properties they responsible for. Since I am mutating the Input data directly, the parent object is up to date immediately.
I want to refactor the child components to receive a clone of the data object, so I follow best practices by not mutating the input. I set up Output events in each child to update the parent of the properties that should be changed.
The problem is I do not know the correct time to emit the children output. I have a submit button on the parent, calling submitForm(). How can I then get the updated values from the children? I can only think of creating some kind of input for the children that lets them know its's time to update the parent, but that feels wrong.

I actually had this exact problem recently. I ended up making the children adhere to an interface with a designated method the parent can call, putting a template variable on each child, and using ViewChildren to fetch the children so I can call the method on them from the parent when I need their changes. I regretted going in that direction though.

I have a habit of not breaking my components up enough. When I do, I always run into this input output problem and it makes me think what is the point of making all these child components if I have to do all this extra work to make them communicate...

In my case, I had to split them up for my sanity and maintainability. The parent was ~500 lines, and was accumulating arguably-irrelevant logic. There were clear divisions of responsibility for the irrelevant-logic, so what children I needed was pretty clear, so I went that way. But ya, then communication became a pain.

Thanks. So your suggestion is in the parent, to create a ViewChild component reference for each child and then call their emit/update property methods at the time of form submission?

Basically (I used ViewChildren because the children were also a bit dynamic), but like I said, this wasn't great. Apparently, parents calling child methods is an  anti-pattern. I upvoted this because I'm also interested in how this should be done. I regret not asking my own question at the time.

@Carcigenicate I think I found a solution. I knew I could do it this way but it seems like a ton of work just to avoid mutating an child input object...which would have avoided all this.

So I believe I found a decent way. I created a service that I can reuse.
export class SharedService {
  private subject = new Subject<string>();

  setSubject(value: string) {
    this.subject.next(value);
  }

  getSubject(): Observable<string> {
    return this.subject.asObservable();
  }
}

// In parent component
this.sharedService.setSubject('updateParentModel');  // child will fire off emit

// In child component
  @Input() dataObject;
  @Output() updateParent = new EventEmitter();
  destroy$: Subject<void> = new Subject();

  ngOnDestroy(): void {
    this.destroy$.next();
    this.destroy$.complete();
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.dataObject = { ...this.dataObject }  // create (shallow) clone

    this.sharedService.getSubject()
    .pipe(takeUntil(this.destroy$))
    .subscribe({ 
      next: (res: string) => {
        if (res == 'updateParentModel') { 
          this.updateParentModel();
        }
      }
    });
  }

  updateParentModel = (): void => {
    this.updateParent.emit(this.dataObject);
  }

